# raster_geometry.sphere is giving different volumes when only the position changes

Tags: python, numpy, simpleitk

I have a set of midpoints (from labelled tumours within a set of scans [512x512x512 voxels]).
I'm just trying to create a sphere with a radius of 10 voxels at each midpoint. To do this, I'm using raster_geometry.sphere and defining the position as the midpoint/512 (i.e. position = midpoint/ 512 , raster_geometry.sphere(512, 10, positon) )

When I'm doing this, however, the volume of the sphere changes. Is there something I don't understand about raster_geometry?

```
from logzero import logger as logging
from lama import common
import numpy as np
import SimpleITK as sitk
import raster_geometry as rg

for i, img_path in enumerate(scan_paths):
    logging.info(img_path)
    logging.info(tumour_paths[i])

    m_loader = common.LoadImage(tumour_paths[i])
    mask = m_loader.img

    m_array = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(mask)

    s = ndimage.find_objects(m_array)[-1]

    midpoint = [(np.mean([s[0].start, s[0].stop]))/512,
                (np.mean([s[1].start, s[1].stop]))/512,
                (np.mean([s[2].start, s[2].stop]))/512]

    print("Original Midpoint", [i*512 for i in midpoint])

    print("Modified midpoint", midpoint)

    arr = rg.sphere(512, 10, midpoint).astype(np.int_)

    print(np.count_nonzero(arr))
    print(np.sum(arr))
```

Example output is below:

```
[I 220525 17:37:58 radiomics_normaliser:86] E:\220204_BQ_dataset\220521_BQ_norm\imgs\200721_MPTLVo3_GFSeeds_4T1R_4T1R_D7_C1_002.nrrd
[I 220525 17:37:58 radiomics_normaliser:87] E:\220204_BQ_dataset\220521_BQ_norm\tumour_respaced\200721_MPTLVo3_GFSeeds_4T1R_4T1R_D7_C1_002.nrrd
Original Midpoint [260.5, 252.5, 162.0]
Modified midpoint [0.5087890625, 0.4931640625, 0.31640625]
4160
4160
[I 220525 17:38:14 radiomics_normaliser:86] E:\220204_BQ_dataset\220521_BQ_norm\imgs\200721_MPTLVo3_GFseeds_4T1R_4T1R_D7_C1_003.nrrd
[I 220525 17:38:14 radiomics_normaliser:87] E:\220204_BQ_dataset\220521_BQ_norm\tumour_respaced\200721_MPTLVo3_GFseeds_4T1R_4T1R_D7_C1_003.nrrd
Original Midpoint [219.5, 234.5, 165.5]
Modified midpoint [0.4287109375, 0.4580078125, 0.3232421875]
4165
4165
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How much does the volume change?  Is it simply a sampling issue, where it changes a bit depending on the shift in voxel locations?

Comment: @DaveChen so the maximum range was around 25 voxels.
I've rounded the midpoint values  and added smoothing=True and the maximum range drops to 5 voxels. 
Does raster_geometry use sampling? Is there a way to improve the sampling?

Comment: Rasterization is fundamentally a sampling problem.  You are sampling a continuous function (the circle) at pixel center locations. Small shifts in the center can change which pixels are deemed inside the circle. Rounding and smoothing will reduce the variation.

Comment: The simplest way of improving the rasterization is adding more boxes, i.e. increasing the shape sizes (and all other sizes).

Answer (score 0):

This is a fundamental issue with rasterization.

Let's try to illustrate this with ASCII pictures.

Assume we want to represent a line of length `2` starting at `0` in a raster with say `4` cells:

```
        0       1       2       3       4
raster: |_._._._|_._._._|_._._._|_._._._|
  line:  - - - - - - - -
```

If the cells can only have boolean values, when we count the number of "True" cells and use it as a proxy for the length of the line we get `2`. Nice.

What does happen if the line starts at `0.5` instead of `0`?

Graphically this is:

```
        0       1       2       3       4
raster: |_._._._|_._._._|_._._._|_._._._|
  line:      - - - - - - - -
```

Now the line spans 3 cells. If we count the half-filled cells as "True", then the counting method will give us a value of 3 for the length of the line.
Conversely, if we count the half-filled cells as "False", we get 1.

So, how can we fix this? In this case we could say we count one cell as "True" and one as "False", and we break even.

This is however not ideal. What if the length of our line is `2.25` to begin with? No matter how smart we are at counting the "True" cells, we will not get to the correct result.

A more effective approach would be store not just if the cell is filled (partially) or not, but also how much is filled (from 0 to 1), i.e. to use fractional weighting instead of boolean.

Using the `2.25` line length and the rest from the above examples, one would get:

```
        0       1       2       3       4
raster: |_._._._|_._._._|_._._._|_._._._|
  line:  - - - - - - - - -
```

so, we store in the cells: `[1, 1, 0.25, 0]`.

If the line now starts at `0.5` this is also not an issue, as the values within the cells will tell us how much of the line is in each cell:

```
        0       1       2       3       4
raster: |_._._._|_._._._|_._._._|_._._._|
  line:      - - - - - - - - -
```

and precisely: `[0.5, 1, 0.75, 0]` which again sum up to `2.25`.

For lines it is comparatively easy to produce such an estimate.

For complex shapes this is less simple and a *tentative* approach is provided in `raster_geometry` and it is activated only when the `smoothing` parameter is set to `True`.

---

A different approach would be to replace larger cells with more smaller cells, i.e. higher resolution.
This way the precision is achieved at the expenses of memory.

In ASCII pictures, if each cell is split into four, the 2.25 size becomes `2.25 * 4 = 9`:

```
        0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
raster: |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
  line:  - - - - - - - - -
```

For linear problems, the memory "price" of higher resolution is: `size(bool) / size(float)`.

For NumPy on 64bit machines this is `8 / 64 = 8`, so higher resolution will result in a much coarser length estimate, up to 1/8th of the cell size.

Also, resolution scales poorly with higher dimensions, as for 2D we need to take the square root, for 3D the cubic root, for N-D the n-th root.
For example, in 3D the same memory will result in a 1/2 of the cell size precision.

Of course, with higher resolution one would get extra information on *where* the extra weight is located, so the above discussion only apply to measuring the object sizes (and related quantities like area, volume, etc.).